# What's the fastest way to apply a function across multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, dictionary

Is there a way to do something like this

```
Array_a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
Array_b = [[4,3],[2,1]] #(anything really)
a_list = [1,2,3,4]
def any_function(x,y,a_list):
    a_list.append(x).append(y)
    return min(a_list)
```

And then pass Array_a and Array_b in argument and then end up with a array as a result.

I want to use a function that takes several argument. I want to run that function multiple times with my arguments being element of 2 identical arrays and put the results in a new identical shaped arrays.

Of course I could use a loop, but is there a faster way, using map or something. 
Thx!

Comment: The numpy module has this kind of functionality, can you use it?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? I didn't manage to make it work

Comment: `alist.append(3).append(3)` does not work.  `append` changes `alist` in-place, and cannot be chained.

Comment: What do you mean by `array`.  You show lists and lists of lists,  as well as list operations.  List comprehension is a nice way of iterating on lists, but it only mildly faster than more explicit loops.  With `numpy` arrays, you can move many operations into compiled code, which is much faster.  BUT, converting lists to arrays takes time, so there are plenty of cases where list operations are still faster.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of output you're looking for; what do you expect when running your two arrays through this function?  For an intro to this approach (numpy vectorization) see for example: https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html

Comment: Seems like my post isn't clear. I am looking to run a function using 2 argument, any function that returns a number, and map it across 2 identical shaped array and return another array.

The function itself doesn't have anything to do with arrays